# Determining argument types of a C function from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, core-foundation

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a Core Foundation function and use it in my code. I've determined the number of arguments required for this function as being just 1, and I'm 99% sure the function is meant to take a single `CFStringRef` and return a `CFStringRef`. So I declared the function like so:

```
extern CFStringRef CPPhoneNumberCopyFormattedStringForTextMessage(CFStringRef pnString);
```

And then I proceeded to try to put it to use:

```
CFStringRef formattedAddress = CPPhoneNumberCopyFormattedStringForTextMessage((CFStringRef)@"test");
```

But when I compile, I get a familiar `symbol not found` error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"CPPhoneNumberCopyFormattedStringForTextMessage(__CFString const*)", referenced from: ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Now, normally I would just assume I'm wrong with at least one of my guesses regarding the function's signature (ie. number of arguments, argument type, etc), but in this case I've gone over the assembly again and again, and the only signature that makes sense is the one I've provided. I know I'm linking to the correct framework, and I've run `nm` to make sure the symbol for the function is in fact there.

So I guess my question has 2 parts:

1. Is there something I'm missing here?
2. Is there a better way to determine the number of arguments and / or the argument types a C function like this takes to satisfy the compiler?

I'm no expert on how a compiler / linker works, but I figure it must be doing something that I can take advantage of if it relies on an accurate function declaration to link to that function correctly. What is it checking for, exactly? The `sizeof` for each argument? And is there a way I can leverage this to determine the function's arguments more easily than educated guessing?

I can provide assembly code and any other information if that would be helpful.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm running on iOS 5.1, so this is compiled for ARM (armv7 to be exact). I'm compiling using the latest version of Clang. The framework is a fat binary for both armv6 and armv7.

Comment: Nobody can 'guess' a calling convention for a particular platform, read the compiler manual. Also please don't post questions like this without mentioning which compiler you are using.

Comment: Well if the function is not open, I personally would not use it as it could disappear from subsequent versions. Have you tried two arguments such as (CFStringRef, CFMutableStringRef) since Copy is in the function's name?

Comment: Have you verified which framework the function is in? Perhaps you've gotten the argument list right, but you aren't linking against the necessary framework.

Comment: Is this a compiler error or a linker error?  With C the only checks that I know of for argument lists are when the compiler is processing the source code.  The linker gets object code with symbols for externals however the linker is just plugging in addresses for external symbols in static libraries or the stubs for dynamic/shared libraries.  If the linker says not found then it is missing from your object files and/or library list.   I am unfamiliar with the @ symbol in the call.  what is that?

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, forgot to mention that. I'm running on iOS 5.1, so this is using ARM (armv7 to be exact). I'm compiling using the latest version of Clang, but I'm not sure which compiler was used to compile the framework I'm linking to (my guess is Clang though). The framework is a fat binary for both armv6 and armv7. I'll update the question with this as well.

Also, I didn't guess the number of arguments, I inferred it by checking which registers are used in the function's assembly. It only uses `R0`, so that's why I'm quite sure it takes only 1 argument.

Comment: @PeterHosey I've verified it using `nm`, yes. I've checked the console output at compile time and I am linking to the same framework the function is defined in.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue I'm aware it could disappear, but I've made sure this function is available in all foreseeable versions of the OS so far (from iOS 4.x to iOS 6), so I'm not too concerned with availability at the moment. I've tried a few variations (like CFMutableStringRef) with the function, but I didn't want to be guessing all day, which is why I'm looking for potentially better ways to figure out what argument types are being used.

Comment: @RichardChambers It's a linker error. I've encountered issues like this before, where changing the argument types for the function I'm linking to (by declaring it using `extern`) actually affects whether the linker links to the function successfully or not. What confuses me is why or how that works, because I'm not aware of a way to directly detect the argument types (or number of arguments) without inferring it with assembly code. The @ symbol is used to create an `NSString`, which is then cast to a `CFStringRef` (Objective-C allows you to do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you're using a C++ compiler to compile your code.  If you put the prototype of `CPPhoneNumberCopyFormattedStringForTextMessage` in an `extern "C"` block, it should link, as the name mangling will not be done.  Determining the types is another matter entirely.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something. Worked perfectly once I made that change. I'm using Objective-C++, which I didn't consider until your answer.